# Openssl library with debugging symbols

Tags: debugging, openssl, static-libraries

I recently built `openssl-1.0.1l` (with debugging symbols) from source. I wrote a `C` program that performs some basic cryptography using the openssl library functions. When the executable is run, along with the results, it displays some information (as shown below) to the `stdout`.

```
Ending BN_CTX_start 
(0x9b03300): 008 001 001 001
   : ^^^         ^^^ 
Starting BN_CTX_get
(0x9b03300): 008 001 001 001 
   : ^^^         ^^^ 
Starting BN_CTX_end
(0x9b03300): 008 001 001 001 010 
   : ^^^         ^^^ 
Ending BN_CTX_end
(0x9b03300): 008 001 001 001 
   : ^^^ 
Starting BN_CTX_end
(0x9b03300): 008 001 001 001 
   : ^^^ 
Ending BN_CTX_end
(0x9b03300): 
   : 
BN_CTX_free, stack-size=32, pool-bignums=16
dmaxs: 08 01 01 01 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

What is this 'extra' information? Why is it being output? Is there a way to disable it? I require my executable to only perform what it is intended to perform.

This is a part of the code. This piece of code is sufficient to cause the above issue:

```
#include <openssl/ecdsa.h>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>

int main()
{
    EC_KEY *keyPair = EC_KEY_new();
    EC_GROUP *curve = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_sect163k1);
    EC_KEY_set_group(keyPair, curve);
    EC_KEY_generate_key(keyPair);
}
```

Comment: What is the extra information you are referring to? You need to show the source code that's printing it. You usually do this sort of thing under GDB, and not with STDOUT. Under gdb, you should also issue `show shared` to ensure you are loading the OpenSSL library you expect. You might be loading the system's version of the library.

Comment: @jww The above information (that is shown) is the extra information that I am referring to. No, I am not using gdb. I am simply running the executable. But as I mentioned, the library is built with debugging symbols (by using the option -d with configure). I have ensured that I am not using the system's version of the library. I will update my qyestion with relevant source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried configuring it with the `-UBN_CTX_DEBUG` flag.

Open `Configure`. Find the table entry:

```
"debug",    "gcc:-DBN_DEBUG -DREF_CHECK -DCONF_DEBUG -DBN_CTX_DEBUG 
  -DCRYPTO_MDEBUG -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM -ggdb -g2 -Wformat -Wshadow -Wmissing-prototypes 
  -Wmissing-declarations -Werror::(unknown)::-lefence::::",
```

Remove `-DBN_CTX_DEBUG`. You should probably change `-g2` to `-g3` so you symbolic defines are retained, too.

Then, `./Configure debug`.

---

> Openssl [1.0.2] library with debugging symbols

I've found the easiest way to do this is....

First, `make clean && make dclean` to tidy up and delete the recursive makefiles.

Second, open `Makefile.org` and change `CFLAG= -O` to `CFLAG= -Og -g3` (or `CFLAG= -O0 -g3` if GCC does *not* support `-Og`).

Third, open `Configure` and copy one of the pre-existing configuration targets (like `linux-generic64`). Rename it to something like `my-config`. Remove anything related to `-Ox` and `-gX` (or add `-Og -g3` there, too). Also remove things like `-fomit-frame-pointer`.

Fourth, make with your configuration:

```
./Configure my-config
make
make install
```

As an alternate way to do it, pick one of the developer's pre-configured configurations. For example, Ben Laurie is a developer, and you can use `./Configure debug-ben-no-opt`. It build with `-O0 -g3`.

---

Its also noteworthy that the configuration table in `Configure` has gone away in OpenSSL Master (the stuff that's expected to be 1.1.0 and above).

What you have in its stead is a `Configurations` folder. In the folder, you have CONF files like `10-main.conf` with entries like:

```
%targets = (
    ...
    ##### MacOS X (a.k.a. Darwin) setup
    "darwin-common" => {
        template         => 1,
        cc               => "cc",
        cflags           => "",
        debug_cflags     => "-g -O0",
        release_cflags   => "-O3",
        thread_cflag     => "-D_REENTRANT",
        sys_id           => "MACOSX",
        lflags           => "-Wl,-search_paths_first%",
        bn_ops           => "BN_LLONG RC4_CHAR RC4_CHUNK DES_UNROLL BF_PTR",
        perlasm_scheme   => "osx32",
        dso_scheme       => "dlfcn",
        shared_target    => "darwin-shared",
        shared_cflag     => "-fPIC -fno-common",
        shared_ldflag    => "-dynamiclib",
        shared_extension => ".\$(SHLIB_MAJOR).\$(SHLIB_MINOR).dylib",
    },
    ...
    "darwin-i386-cc" => {
        inherit_from     => [ "darwin-common", asm("x86_asm") ],
        cflags           => "-arch i386 -DL_ENDIAN",
        release_cflags   => "-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer",
        bn_ops           => "BN_LLONG RC4_INT RC4_CHUNK DES_UNROLL BF_PTR",
        perlasm_scheme   => "macosx",
        shared_ldflag    => "-arch i386 -dynamiclib",
    },
    "darwin64-x86_64-cc" => {
        inherit_from     => [ "darwin-common", asm("x86_64_asm") ],
        cflags           => "-arch x86_64 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall",
        bn_ops           => "SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG RC4_CHUNK DES_INT DES_UNROLL",
        perlasm_scheme   => "macosx",
        shared_ldflag    => "-arch x86_64 -dynamiclib",
    },
);
```

I'm actually suffering similar, but on 1.1.0 (master) with Clang and its sanitizers. Here's my broken `99-clang-sanitize.conf` that attempts to do similar to what you are doing (modifying `CFLAGS`):

```
%targets = (
    "darwin-sanitize-x86_64" => {
        sys_id           => "MACOSX",
        # inherit_from     => [ asm("x86_64_asm") ],    
        cc               => "clang",
        cflags           => "-g3 -O1 -fPIC -Wall -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -arch x86_64 -DL_ENDIAN",
        lflags           => "-arch x86_64",
        bn_ops           => "SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG RC4_CHUNK DES_INT DES_UNROLL",
        thread_cflag     => "-D_REENTRANT",
        # perlasm_scheme   => "osx64",
        dso_scheme       => "dlfcn",
        # engines_obj     => "e_padlock-x86_64.o"       
    },
    "darwin-sanitize-i386" => {
        sys_id           => "MACOSX",
        # inherit_from     => [ asm("x86_asm") ],   
        cc               => "clang",
        cflags           => "-g3 -O1 -fPIC -Wall -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -arch i386 -DL_ENDIAN",
        lflags           => "-arch i386",
        bn_ops           => "BN_LLONG RC4_INT RC4_CHUNK DES_UNROLL BF_PTR",
        thread_cflag     => "-D_REENTRANT",
        # perlasm_scheme   => "osx32",
        dso_scheme       => "dlfcn",
        # engines_obj     => "e_padlock-x86.o"
    },
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have posted the steps that I have followed. Changing the *debug* table entry of the `Configure` file and configuring with `./Configure debug` gave me some issues. So, I tried some other ways and finally found one. Thanks for the information about `openssl-1.0.2`.

Answer (score 3):

If you look into `crypto/bn/bn_ctx.c` file, you can see that the messages are result of `BN_CTX_DEBUG` preprocessor directive.

It is disabled by default. Which command did you used to configure OpenSSL build? Try `./config -d` if you need only debugging symbols.

Comment: I used `./config -d` because I need only the debugging symbols. Is there a way to disable these messages?

Comment: These messages do not show up when the library is configured with `./config`. But then, I need the debugging symbols.

Comment: Ah, I found out in `Configure` file that the directive is defined with debug build on some platforms, not mine. Try undefining it by `./config -d -UBN_CTX_DEBUG`.

Comment: I tried configuring it with the `-UBN_CTX_DEBUG` flag. But the issue still remains. Can you suggest any other alternatives? Thank you for the help. The messages show up when running `make test` too.

Comment: After a few more unsuccessful attempts, I surrender to do it the right way :) Open `Configure`, find the line with flags for your architecture, and remove `-DBN_CTX_DEBUG` from there.

Answer (score 1):

These are the exact steps that I followed to install `openssl-1.0.1l` with debugging symbols and without the extra information:

1. When I run the `config -d` command, the last line of the output says **Configured for debug-linux-elf**. In the `Configure` file, I changed the table entry for **debug-linux-elf** by removing `-DBN_CTX_DEBUG`.
2. I didn't change the `-g` flag that was in that particular table entry.
3. Run the following:
   `./config -d`
   `make`
   `make test`
   `sudo make install`.

The problem seems to be fixed. Thanks @jww for the answer.